# Trouble Returning WCS from FITS Image

Tags: python, astropy, wcs

I am using astropy to load a FITS image and retrieve the WCS from it.

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS

with fits.open('hst_A2744_f606w_drz.fits') as hdul:
    wcs = WCS(hdul[1])
    print(wcs)
```

Which Returns

```
WCS Keywords

Number of WCS axes: 2
CTYPE : 'RA---TAN'  'DEC--TAN'
CRVAL : 3.587755699764648  -30.39711750881429
CRPIX : 3000.4999999998081  2989.499999999809
CD1_1 CD1_2  : -1.3888888888888e-05  0.0
CD2_1 CD2_2  : 0.0  1.3888888888889599e-05
NAXIS : 6000  5978
```

My goal is to return CRVAL as either a string, tuple, or array like this:
`(3.587755699764648, -30.39711750881429)`

I've tried accessing it as `wcs['CTYPE']` and `wcs[CTYPE]`, and `wcs.CTYPE` but all return errors.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`WCS.wcs`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.WCS.html#astropy.wcs.WCS)

and specifically [`WCS.wcs.crval`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.Wcsprm.html#astropy.wcs.Wcsprm.crval) (or `WCS.wcs.ctype` since in your question you wrote you want the `CRVAL` values but you showed attempts to find the `CTYPE` values).